# SQL: Column B entries of column A are also in column A --> Match column C attribute of A's B entry in A to original A

Tags: sql, sql-server

in a SQL server database *SQLBASE* I have a table *article* with three columns:

*artnr* (Article number)

*succesor* (Successor article number)

*color* (Color of article number)

Not every article number must have a successor number, but every successor number is always also listed somewhere in column A, like below:

**Input**

```
Article1   |   Article3    |   green

Article2   |    empty      |   blue

Article3   |   Article2    |   red

Article4   |    empty      |   yellow
```

For any article number of column A I need the color of the corresponding successor number (if there is any successor, otherwise leave blank).

**Output:**

```
Article1   |   red

Article2   |   empty

Article3   |   blue

Article4   |   empty
```

Please, I would appreciate any help on how to link the successor material's color to the predecessor material using an SQL query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `self join`:

```
select a1.artnr, a2.color
from Articles a1 left join Articles a2
on a1.succesor = a2.artnr
```